# Dark theme turns off after reboot

Tags: 20.04

It always worked for me from day one. But lately I decided to install BackSlide to rice my setup a little. Since I've done this ever time I turn the laptop back on default light mode is enabled and I have to turn dark mode back on again.

If there's any important information I didn't include please tell me. Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
I uninstalled BackSlide (which was a gnome extension actually) and the problem persisted. I noticed that on booting in the Tweak's menu the global Applications theme was set to blank. Not the default, just blank.

Comment: Uninstall the software.  Does this solve the problem?  If so, you might consider filing a bug report with the developer of that software.

Comment: @Nmath Tried it but didn't work